# Spark sql query by ids contained in array

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible to query spark sql by ids?

Ideally what I'm looking for is something like this

```
val ids = ["123", "345", "456", "972"]
df.filter(df("id") in ids)
```

Another idea scenario would be if I could even pass in a dataframe that has a single column.

```
val ids = df.map(r => r.getString(1))
dataDf.filter(dataDF("id" in ids)
```

Comment: @cheseaux Dataframes have a collection behind them, its more of create a dataframe, then for a specific value go query values by that id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, but you can use [isin](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@isin(list:Any*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to filter based on a list of values. Here is an example

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3)).toDF("id")
df.show

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
+---+
```

Then you can filter using a List/Seq/Array that you have to convert to a vararg like this :

```
val ids = Array(1,2)
df.filter(df("id").isin(ids:_*)).show

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
+---+
```

Or you could also write directly `df.filter(df("id").isin(1,2))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by something like ... `df.filter($"id".isin( ids: _* ))`. For more information look at the documentation of `isin()` defined on the [`org.apache.spark.sql.Column`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column) class